# config parser printing blanks

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, config

just for fun (and who knows i might use it later), i wrote a config file parser in c++. it didnt seem to difficult, and couldnt see any problem while i writing it. however, when i tested it out, the config parser wasnt capturing anything. ive gone through the code three times. would anyone be able to tell me the issue?

```
#include <istream> // for std::basic_stream<char> (aka std::string)
#include <string> // for std::basic_string<char> (aka std::string)
#include <map> // for std::map<t, t>
#include <cctype> // for character type testing, c style

std::map<std::string, std::string> configParser(std::istream &stream, const char &comment, const char &seperator) {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> options; // to hold key, value pairs
    std::string key, value; // so options[key] = value
    bool seperatorFound; // for differentiating between key and value

    while(stream) { // operate on the stream while its good
        char current = stream.get(); // current will hold the next character returned from the stream

        if(current == '\n') { // current is a newline
            options[key] = value; // add the key, value pair as an option found
            key = ""; // reset key
            value = ""; // reset value
            seperatorFound = false; // reset seperatorFound
            continue; // jump back up to the top
        }

        else if(isspace(current)) { // current is one of: \r, \t, [SPACE]
            continue; // eat the white space and jump back up to the top
        }

        else if(current == comment) { // current is a comment marker
            getline(stream, key, '\n'); // eat the rest of the line. i use key since its alreay there
                                        // no since in creating a string object to eat a line
            key = ""; // reset key
            continue; // jump back up to the top
        }

        else if(current == seperator) { // current is a seperator marker
            seperatorFound = true; // update the seperator state
            continue; // jump back up to the top
        }

        else { // current must be a symbol
            if(!seperatorFound) { // haven't found the seperator yet. as a result, must be a key
                key += current; // give key the next letter
                continue; // jump back up to the top
            }

            // otherwise, it must be a value
            value += current; // give value the next letter instead.
        }
    }

    return options;
}

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> options;
    std::string line;

    while(true) {
        getline(std::cin, line);
        std::istringstream stream(line);

        options = configParser(stream, '#', ':');

        for(auto iterator = options.begin(); iterator != options.end(); iterator++) {
            std::cout<< iterator->first <<" : "<< iterator->second << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout<< std::endl << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Colin spotted the error, I think; but in general just do some debugging, one way or another, to find errors. Even simple printf debugging would have helped here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 1:** Your `line` doesn't actually contain a newline character, because `getline` discards it. A possible solution is: `std::istringstream stream(line + '\n');`

**Issue 2:** `seperatorFound` is not initialized. It should be initialized to false.

**Issue 3:** You should check whether the stream is good *after* you get a character. That is, you should do:

```
while(true) {
    char current = stream.get();
    if (!stream) break;
```

Comment: ok thank you... so i was just being stupid then... also, why should i check afterwards? what if its not good and then i try to extract a character? wouldnt it be invalid since i didnt test it?

Comment: Yes, it's true that it shouldn't make a difference here, but it's good practice to do so, since there are cases where it matters.

Comment: care to expand? not trying to be difficult. i just havent done a lot of real world programming so im curious when one might do so

Comment: Well, the thing is that the way you do it now the loop body runs one more time than it needs to. A trivial example where this might lead to undesired behaviour is reading the contents of a stream and dumping them in a file: The last character of the stream would be written to the file twice.

Comment: ah ok i see what you mean

Answer (score 2):

Your parser mostly works, but the wrapper does not. getline does not capture the '\n', and your parser will not capture a result from a line without a '\n'.

Simplify your main() to:

```
int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> options;
    std::string line;

    options = configParser(std::cin, '#', ':');

    for(auto iterator = options.begin(); iterator != options.end(); iterator++) {
        std::cout<< iterator->first <<" : "<< iterator->second << std::endl;
    }

     std::cout<< std::endl << std::endl;
}
```

and it mostly works.

Comment: Why not `for(auto const & p : options) std::cout << p.first etc`?

Comment: well see i had that, but wouldnt the parser go on forever?